# Removing punctuation from an array of strings fuction

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I am currently doing a project in JavaScript that involves me removing certain punctuation from an array of strings (like the array "greetings"). I used an iterator to loop through each item in the array, then I wrote a loop to loop through each letter in the current item. I declared an empty variable that I used to concatenate each letter based on if the letter is not double quotes, period, or an exclamation point. Then after the all the letters in the word have been looped through, I then return the final concatenated string into the map iterator. When I try to print out noPunctGreetings, I get empty strings.

```js
const greetings = ['Hi,', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Dave!']

const noPunctGreetings = greetings.map(word => {
  let concatedWord = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] != '"' || word[i] != '.' || word[i] != '!') {
      concatedWord.concat(word[i].toLowerCase());
    } 
  }
  return concatedWord;
})

console.log(noPunctGreetings)

>>> ['', '', '', '', '']
```

If there is another cleaner way to do this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat

> The concat() method concatenates the string arguments to the calling string and returns a new string.

So you need to do

```
concatedWord = concatedWord.concat(word[i].toLowerCase());
```

Also, you need to do:

```
word[i] != '"' && word[i] != '.' && word[i] != '!'
```

instead of `||`, since `word[i]` will always be either not `"` or not `.`

```js
const greetings = ['Hi,', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Dave!']

const noPunctGreetings = greetings.map(word => {
  let concatedWord = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word[i] != '"' && word[i] != '.' && word[i] != '!') {
      concatedWord = concatedWord.concat(word[i].toLowerCase());
    } 
  }
  return concatedWord;
})

console.log(noPunctGreetings)
```

Or, more simply:

```js
const greetings = ['Hi,', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Dave!']

const noPunctGreetings = greetings.map(word => word.replace(/[."!]/g, "").toLowerCase())

console.log(noPunctGreetings)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!